# How do I remove table borders with python-docx?

Tags: python, docx, python-docx

I can't remove the border of tables in Python-docx.

Answer (score -2):

This worked for me.

```
table = document.add_table(rows=1, cols=2)
for row in table.rows:
    for cell in row.cells:
        tc = cell._element.tcPr
        tc.left = None
        tc.top = None
        tc.right = None
        tc.bottom = None
        cell.vertical_alignment = WD_CELL_VERTICAL_ALIGNMENT.CENTER
        cell.paragraphs[0].alignment = WD_TABLE_ALIGNMENT.CENTER
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).